# Should a helper function that remove duplicate spaces also trim the string?

Tags: c#, design, architecture, coding-style

In my opinion it should not since it violates single responsibility principle, but I am finding myself often calling both.

**Edit:** here are the 'boring' details:
As you all know, we cannot escape the existence of an `Util` class. It simply exists. I have a `static class Util` that has some helper methods, and there dwells `RemoveDuplicateSpaces` along with:

`NormalizeWhitespaces` - replaces all Spacing characters with spaces and \r\n with \n
`StripSpaces`- removes all spaces

As some comments and answers pointed out, my problem falls in line with finding a good name to a function that does both. But how to do so without further littering the class? Trimming a string and removing duplicate spaces are similar and yet, different things.

Comment: If you call your method NormalizeWhitespace there is no SRP issue. And if you are still concerned you can call Trim and RemoveDoubleSpaces from inside NormalizeWhitespace.

Comment: @MartinMaat I already have a `NormalizeWhitespace`: it replaces all spacing characters with spaces and \r\n with \n. De-duplicating spaces and trimming should not be named NormalizeWhitespace simply because whitespaces are more than spaces. However I do concede that my problem falls more in line to creating/naming an appropriate function that does both

Comment: What did you name the function? This makes a big difference.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I named it `RemoveDuplicateSpaces`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the name of the function. This is crucial to the question and gets lost too easily in comments.

Comment: @GregBurghardt: though I think your suggestion would be usually ok, in this case it could encourage the OP to edit the question in a way it could possibly invalidate some answers it already got.

Comment: @DocBrown: This is the trouble I get into. I see a question that very clearly needs some more information, so I ask for it instead of down voting and voting to close it. Other people jump in to answer way too early. The OP clarifies a few things --- a needed clarification. Then my suggestion to edit the question to clarify it is met with resistance. I might post something on meta. I could use some... well... clarification.

Comment: *"Other people jump in to answer way too early."* - sorry we did not wait for you, and sorry we thought the question was answerable already with the provided information. And sorry that exactly such an answer was accepted by the OP, and it was not yours. ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What did you name it?

Depending on the name this is either a good idea or a terrible one.

```
stripExtraSpaces();

removeDuplicateSpaces();

trim();
```

A single responsibly isn’t about ensuring that it’s impossible to decompose the function. Its about staying true to its name, its one idea, its, well, single responsibility.

Each responsibility is usually made up of many smaller responsibilities. Your job is to make sure the smaller responsibilities don’t surprise anyone when they are found together.

So what you need is a name that lets you put together these different responsibilities. Pick a good name and people won’t have to keep looking inside to remember what it does.

The best names not only tell you what belongs in the method but also what doesn’t belong. Fail to make that clear and you violate the single responsibility principle simply because people aren’t sure what this is until they look inside.

If you have good names for those other responsibilities use them. Good names are the most limited resource in programming. Do not waste them.

Comment: I agree. Your answer made me realize that I should have asked what would be a good name to a function that does both; Thanks for the input

Answer (score 6):

The SRP means different things on different levels of abstraction:

- at the lowest level, there should be functions where each one does a basic operations. If you see "remove duplicate spaces" as one operation, and "trim" as a different one, make two functions, one for each.
- one step higher in the abstraction hierarchy, you may have functions which coordinate these basic operations. So combining the calls to `Trim` and `RemoveDuplicateSpaces` into a new function does not violate the SRP - the single reponsibility of the new function is to orchestrate the calls to the other two. If you would not allow this, you would never be able to create larger programs from smaller building bricks (at least not by following the SRP).

Note this approach incorporates another principle - the "Single Level of Abstraction" principle, which means all operations within a function should be on the same level of abstraction, and not mix lower and higher level abstractions.

However, in this case, removing unneeded spaces at the begin, end and in the middle of a string can be also interpreted as equivalent operations. So if put these operations directly into one function and give it a suitable name (for example, `RemoveSuperfluousWhitespace`, or `NormalizeWhitespace`, as MartinMaat suggested in a comment), it is not an SRP violation from that point of view, and it also follows the SLA.

Comment: good point. Your answer and @candied-orange's answer made me see that this is about finding a good name to a method that does both things. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 3):

The function should do what it is supposed to do, nothing more, nothing less. Bringing in the "Single Responsibility Principle" is absolute nonsense here. You are completely misunderstanding it. If its responsibility is to normalize a string by changing multiple consecutive spaces to a single space and removing leading and trailing spaces, then that is its *single* responsibility.

Comment: Now we only need a good name like `Normalize...()` and we are set.

Comment: Interesting. But following the logic of your answer allows me to create a function  called `Normalize` that normalizes to form D, removes symbols, removes duplicate spaces and trims. Depending on the context of the Helper class, thats OK, but we are talking here about a general utility class. Methods should have well defined scopes and good names, otherwise your utility class will be indistinguishable from garbage. Also, isn't "doing what it is supposed to do" SRP at its core? calling nonsense is really confusing. Well defined names and SRP goes hand in hand. What are you going on about?

Comment: And trimming leading and trailing spaces is somewhat different to removing duplicate spaces. At first when I posted the question I was wondering about if "should i remove all leading and trailing spaces in a function that removes duplicate spaces?" . Now I'm just looking for a good function name that encompasses both things, as other answers pointed out

Answer (score 2):

In one of your comments, you mentioned the function was named `RemoveDuplicateSpaces`.

> I am finding myself often calling both (Trim and RemoveDuplicateSpaces).

If you find that every time you remove duplicate spaces you also trim the string, then you have teased out a single responsibility. It would be annoying to see:

```
foo.RemoveDuplicateSpaces()
   .Trim();

// later on

bar.RemoveDuplicateSpaces()
   .Trim();

// and yet again:

baz.RemoveDuplicateSpaces()
   .Trim();
```

I would wonder, based on the usage of the code, why it doesn't do both, and have a different name. Sometimes the "single responsibility" of a function is discovered by how that code is used.

Comment: I am feeling you grok what are my gripes with this. If, after using RemoveDuplicateSpaces I am often calling Trim, shouldn't I consider removing leading and trailing spaces too inside the method and avoiding all this altogether? - That was the mindset behind my question. Now i see that the consensus is having a good name that accurately portrays what the new method will do. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 1):

If you define your utility functions as [extension methods](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods), you can chain them. This may alleviate the need to have a method that does both, since you can still put all the functionality in one line of code.

```
using Helpers;

var output = input.RemoveDuplicateSpaces().Trim();
```

Although honestly I'd probably not bother with the utility method. It's just one more thing for developers to learn, and the built-in string methods are good enough.

```
var output = input.Replace("  "," ").Trim();
```

If on the other hand there is a specific purpose for this exact string manipulation, I'd probably name the method after *that*, since it more clearly describes what is going on in the code. For example, if you are manipulating the string specifically to display it a certain way, you might write:

```
var output = input.FormatForDisplay();
```

That way the formatting rules are contained in the helper method and not in the calling code, which probably has some different single reason to change.

Comment: `input.RemoveDuplicateSpaces().Trim()` thats what i want to avoid doing; `input.Replace("  "," ").Trim()` : this does not remove duplicate spaces, but double spaces; and the thing about `FormatForDisplay` is that  the fuction is not a formatting rule per se, but string processing/data handling, but I get your point

Answer (score 0):

As for naming the function, why are you trimming and removing duplicate spaces?  Is it to prepare the string for use in a database, API, etc?  For example, looking up a location in a geocoding API?

If so, a name like `prepareLocationForGeocodingAPI()` might be a good name.

Usually I like more generic names, but this may be a case where specific is simpler and better.